# Erro de compilação em Java (Minicraft by Notch)

Tags: java

Eu estou tendo problemas em executar o jogo que o Markus Person Notch criou em 48 horas conhecido com Minicraft (não confunda com Minecraft), eu baixei o código-fonte mas ele dá o seguinte erro de compilação:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at com.mojang.ld22.Game.init(Game.java:118)
    at com.mojang.ld22.Game.run(Game.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

E a janela do jogo permanece branca, não acontece nada.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao código-fonte deste jogo? Se sim, qual a linha 118 da classe Game.java? Parece que ocorreu a tentativa de realizar a leitura de algum arquivo de imagem, na qual não foi encontrada.